# Nashorn JavaScript Invocable.getInterface fails across classloaders in web app

Tags: java, classloader, nashorn, scriptengine, javascript-engine

I need to invoke (with Nashorn) from Java code a function defined in JavaScript and to pass there some parameters. Instead of using Invocable.invokeFunction("Foo", arg1, arg2), I was going to define an interface, then request Invocable to produce its implementation, just like Oracle suggests [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html%20%22here'), "Embedding Oracle Nashorn":

```
package mypackage;
public final class MyClass {
  public interface Composer {
    void compose(final StringBuilder subject, final StringBuilder body);
  }

  public void composeEmail(...) {
      ...
      final ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
      final ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
      engine.eval(scriptText);
      final Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
      final Composer composer = (Composer)invocable.getInterface(Composer);
      composer.compose(subject, body);
      ...
  }
}
```

Problem is, since I am doing this in a web application running in Tomcat, my Composer gets loaded by app-level classloader, while nashorn classes were loaded by extensions class loader. So getInterface fails saying a **TypeError: Can not find a common class loader for ScriptObject and mypackage.Composer**

Any ideas how to overcome that? I could, of course, try to load Composer in a parent classloader, in an assumption (hack-like) that it is actually an ext loader, but there is at least one problem with that: it cannot find my class. I suppose it's quite right: my package resides in my web application, and extension loader does not look there. Any other great ideas?

P.S. And now I noticed that this message is weird: if an app classloader delegates to ext classloader, then of course the latter is the common classloader for them. Maybe they were trying to say that the target interfaces's classloader must be equal to actual implementation's classloader, or the implementation's classloader must delegate to the target's (but not vice versa)?

Comment: Your P.S is probably close to the problem. Be sure not to duplicate classes across classloaders. The interface class might be in the ext classloader AND in the webapp classloader, which takes priority AFAIK. Doesn't look like a code problem, more like a 'which jars are where' problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

Create an instance of `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory` directly instead of doing `engineManager.engineByName()`, then create a `ScriptEngine` by invoking `NashornScriptEngineFactory.getScriptEngine(ClassLoader appLoader)` and passing it your app-level loader.

Comment: Sorry, this gives the same outcome as before. Have you tested that yourself in Tomcat? Seems like either Nashorn's ScriptObject class gets loaded by someone else even before my call to "factory.getScriptEngine(Composer.class.getClassLoader())", or the purpose of the parameter is to specify which loader to use when JS wants to load some app classes (with object construction, for instance), not to specify which loader will load Nashorn's engine itself. I have even read somewhere that Nashorn has to run with elevated privileges (whatever is meant) and thus always is loaded by extension loader.

Comment: I had to use this answer in a undertow filter on wildfly